# Is the set of all polynomials whose coefficients are odd a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

$1.$ The set of all polynomials whose coefficients are all even
is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

This statement is true: take  homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}[x]$  onto $\mathbb{Z_2}[x]$.

Now  my question is  that

$2.$ Is the set of all polynomials whose coefficients are all odd is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]?$

Same logic  in $1.$   or  some other logic is  there ?

Comment: Is the sum of two such polnomials again such a polynomial?

Comment: yes.. sum  is always  @HagenvonEitzen sir

Comment: The sum of two odd numbers is even? That answers the second question. As to the first, you need to be more precise , at least to convince me if no one else.

Comment: Yaaa   @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг take $3 + 5=8$

Comment: but  odd $\times$ odd = odd @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: But a prime ideal is an ideal, so is closed under addition. But 3 and 5 belong in the set while their sum  doesn't. What does that tell you about the set, jasmine? Only multiplication is not sufficient, even addition needs to be respected, right?

Comment: okss  got  its  , thanks u @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг  that  mean $2.$ statement  not  true

Comment: The (co)set in $\,(2)\,$ is $\,1+I\,$ for $\,I = (2) = 2\Bbb Z[x].\,$  But if $I$ is an ideal then its coset $1+I$ is an ideal $\iff I = (1),\,$ since $\,1\in J = 1+I\iff J=(1)\ \ $

Comment: @jasmine Yes jasmine, that is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, it is clear that multiplication by $2$ does not result in another such polynomial.  Thus one of the conditions for an ideal isn't satisfied.